# Laravel livewire Undefined type 'Livewire\Component'

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-livewire

after i added livewire using

`composer require livewire/livewire`

and creating new `livewire component` using

```
php artisan make:livewire search
```

I keep getting an error `Undefined type 'Livewire\Component'`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Search extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search');
    }
}
?>
```

Can you help me please what am i doing wrong here

Comment: did you add the livewire assets??? "@livewireStyles" and "@livewireScripts"???

Comment: Is Livewire loaded through composer? Run `composer show -D`, does it show Livewire? If yes, you could try to reload it, `composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan package:discover`.

Comment: @Prospero Both `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` are all frontend stuff, not related to the PHP class not being found, so that's probably not related, although they are required further down the line.

Comment: Also another thing, you should not close your PHP tags in components - I recommend you remove `?>` at the end there. PHP will self-close at the end, and doing it manually may cause issues in some cases.

Comment: @Qirel thx. I totally agree with your point

Comment: I'm not sure why but creating a new project solved the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you've done all the steps correctly and it's still not working.

Restart VS Code. It solved it for me.

Comment: A restart ended up solving it for me too somehow, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart):

Import livewire in your layout with:

```
...
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    ...
 
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

https://laravel-livewire.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a livewire project for the first time in VS Code, the `intelephense` extension needs VS Code to be restarted once to recognize the dependencies.

I suggest restarting VS code for new composer packages at least once, to avoid undefined type errors, even though you've done everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

restart vs code worked for me

- GOOD PRACTISE when you finish installing a new package it is advisable to restart vs code